# Print Date and Time in a form C++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

could you fix me with my problem? 
I have got a `text` field in `my Form`. And I would like to print Date and Time in a string,I mean, where cursor is.

I got this class for this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
//Russian letters are okay for this
private: System::Void времяИДатаToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


    SYSTEMTIME sys_t;
    GetSystemTime(&sys_t);
    char szFormat[] = "MMMM";
    char Buffer[16];
    sys_t.wMonth = 1; 
    GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, &sys_t, szFormat, Buffer, 256);
}
};
```

I would like to use `MessageBox::Show()` , but it isn't for my problem? 
Can you give some advice for this?

Thanks.

Comment: "could you fix me with my problem?" Ehh "no". That's not how this works. SO is neither a code writing nor a debugging service. You ask *specific* questions; we answer them. We don't just do your work for you.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sorry! I don't want you to do work for me. I've asked for giving some advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

OK, that said: You've got the full .Net library available to you, why not use it?

```
void времяИДатаToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime::Now;
    String^ dateString = now.ToString("MMMM");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. Now I'm on my way to do this. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text field is called `textField`, use:

```
textField->Text = new string(Buffer);
```

Also, your call to

```
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, &sys_t, szFormat, Buffer, 256);
```

Is wrong.  Pass `16`, not `256` as the last argument (because you declared Buffer to have 16 chars).

Comment: It seems to me , my text field isn:t called `textField` . But is it correct to use `richBoxText1`? will it be like `richBoxText1->Text(buffer);`

Comment: I believe you would have to do `richBoxText1->Text = new string(Buffer);`

Comment: Yeah, I got what I needed. Thanks!